# Enable Google Analytics Offline in Angular PWA using service worker

Tags: angular, google-analytics, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I want to have Google Analytics in my PWA application running even when app is offline.
For this the documentation says that we just need to:

1. Install npm install sw-offline-google-analytics
2. Write this in the service worker file
   importScripts('path/to/offline-google-analytics-import.js');
   goog.offlineGoogleAnalytics.initialize();

But I'm not able to do step 2 as I can't find any .js file related to service worker. The only file where I have written some caching related things is the ngsw-config.json file. Please guide me where I can place statements in step 2 so that google analytics runs when app is offline.